# Water Jugs (10, 5 and 6)

Tags: calculation-puzzle, decanting-problems

I have three water jugs, one with 10 liters another with 5 and another with 6, how do i get 8 liters on the first one?

Comment: Which ones of them are full, and which are not?

Answer (score 20):

There is no need for the 5 liters jug. You can do it with only the 10 and 6 liters jugs (and in less steps than the alternate solutions).

1. `10 0 0` $\leftrightarrow$ Fill 10 liters jug.
2. `4  6 0` $\leftrightarrow$ Pour it in the 6 liters jug (now 4 liter in 10 liters jug)
3. `4  0 0` $\leftrightarrow$ Empty 6 liters jug
4. `0  4 0` $\leftrightarrow$ Pour the 4 liter from 10 liters jug to the 6 liters jug (now 4 liter in 6 liters jug)
5. `10 4 0` $\leftrightarrow$ Fill 10 liters jug again
6. `8  6 0` $\leftrightarrow$ Pour water from 10 liters jug to 6 liters jug to fill it

> You will have 8 liter in 10 liters jug

Comment: This seems rather wasteful. I mean, you essentially toss 12 liters of water to get 8.

Comment: @tfitzger That water that he pours out/empties could just as well be poured into the original reservoir from which he filled the 10-liter jug.

Comment: @Shane Not if it's from the tap. =)

Comment: @tfitzger Conserving water is not part of the puzzle as it's currently stated.

Answer (score 12):

Using only exactly 8L:

Assuming 10L, 6L, 5L. Bold indicate refill (top-up or complete)

- 0, **6**, 0 (Using 6 new liters)
- 0, 1, 5
- 1, 0, 5
- 1, 5, 0
- 1, **6**, 0 (Using one new liter)
- 1, 1, 5
- 2, 0, 5
- 2, 5, 0
- 2, **6**, 0 (Using one new liter)
- 8, 0, 0

10 steps, but not a drop of extra water wasted or used.

Comment: I like it. You may take a few more steps, but you waste nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Heres a solution without needing to refil and starting with only 10L.

Jugs are arranged in the following order
10L 5L 6L

Starting with just the 10L jug full

> 10L - 0L --- 0L
>  
>   4   ---- 0 ---- 6
>  
>   4  ---- 5 ---- 1
>  
>   9  ---- 0 ---- 1
>  
>   9 ----  1 ---- 0
>  
>   3 ----  1 ---- 6
>  
>   3 ----  5 ---- 2
>  
>   **8** ----  0 ---- 2

Comment: I like this, no wasting water and no refilling

Comment: still 2L wasted, which is not necessary

Comment: No water is wasted @njzk2 - You've got your 8L needed for whatever purpose, then the remaining 2L in another jug. You have your total 10L still.

Comment: @njzk2 the 2L isn't wasted... it's donated to a local, starving, homeless family and their scrappy-but-lovable dog.

Comment: Of course, donating water to a *thirsty* family would be better; drink some water and you'll still be starving :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that takes more steps than the others, but the problem doesn't say we're trying to minimize steps ;)   It plays on the idea that the 5- and 6-liter jugs allow you to create 1-liter increments as many times as you want.

1. Fill the 6-liter jug.
2. Pour from the 6-liter jug into the 5-liter jug. You have 1 liter remaining in the 6-liter jug.
3. Pour the 1 liter from the 6-liter jug into the 10-liter jug and empty the 5-liter jug.
4. Repeat steps 1–3 7 more times.

It's clunky but simple.

Comment: I like this but I think it's even simpler if you just perform it twice, then dump in on full 6-liter jug

Comment: @Kevin One step faster than my initial thought of "6 into 5, leaving 1... 3 times... then five on top of the 3"

Comment: @Kevin: I had considered that, but I just liked the idea of being able to create any positive integer value using this method.

Answer (score 5):

Fill 10 liters jug.
Pour it in the 6 liter jug.
Pour the remaining 4 liter in the 5 liter jug.
Fill 10 liters again.
Empty the 6 liter jug.
Pour 6 liters from the 10 liter jug in the 6 liter jug.
Put content of 5 liter jug in 10 liter jug.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the 6 liter jug and then pour it into the 10 jug.

- 10 liter jug has 6 liters of water.

Fill the 6 liter jug again and pour 5 liters into the 5 liter jug the remaining 1 liter into the 10 liter jug.

- 10 liter jug has 7 liters of water.

Repeat last step.

- 10 liter jug has 8 liters of water.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all three are empty and you have a tap:

```
10 5 6  Jugs  
 | | |  
 0 0 6   
 0 5 1  
 1 5 0
 1 0 5
 1 0 6
 7 0 0
 7 0 6
 7 5 1
 8 5 0
```

You have 8 liters in the 10L jug and 5 liters in the 5L jug.